# ZF2 console awareness with doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, console, zend-framework2, php-5.5

I'm trying to set up some console capabilities in Zend Framework 2 and I get the gist of the setup, but I also have Doctrine2 included in my composer requirements, and the doctrine cli keeps interceding when I'm trying to get console routing set up in ZF2. Is there any way to keep the doctrine functionality but still get the index.php to accept pre-configured routing commands from the command line interface?

Comment: What command are you running? The last time I ran zf2 from console it was essentially: "php /path/to/index.php myargs"

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what the problem was. I was calling out to the console from phpstorm so I figured it would need quotes around the parameters. For some reason, phpstorm was sending them with the quotes still attached. (probably re-quoting them for me?) so instead of seeing commands like:

```
php.exe public/index.php migration materials
```

it was getting:

```
php.exe public/index.php 'migration' 'materials'
```

Which did not match the configured routing. I so hate it when programs try to think for me.